# Using regular expression to parse limited HTML/XML but with embedded tags

Tags: html, regex

I have the following line in HTML/XML:

```
<p class="myText" style="...">some text here</p>
```

And I use the following regex to capture the content within the 'p' tags:

```
<p\sclass=\"myText\"[^>]*>([^<]*)</p>
```

It worked until today, when the following HTML/XML had some embedded 'i' and 'b' tags within the 'p' tags, like in this sample:

```
<p class="myText" style="...">some <b style="...">bold</b> and <i>italic</I> text here</p>
```

How to modify the regex to get the content within the 'p' tags in this last sample, including the 'b' and 'i' tags?

Comment: [Don't, just don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)

Comment: That is the solution I have currently in place, that now obviously do not work; I am just trying to solve a problem ... any other idea then?

Comment: "any other idea then" — Yes. It is written at the bottom of the answer I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @Quentin, seriously, your suggestion is to use an XML parser for a very limited set of HTML that is by far more efficient to parse with the right regex?  I am not asking to parse HTML pages from the web, just a very specific, well structured HTML/XML string, that I am getting from an API.  All I need is the stop to be on the '</p>', not in the '<' like I am currently doing, and I do not know how to do that, hence the question, which is IMO valid.  Don't you think?

Comment: Valid: yes. Good idea: no. Use an HTML parser. You'll get code you can read and which will be more robust and easier to maintain.

Comment: Fair, but that does not answer the curiosity of how to solve it with regex ... which is the original question.  I am sure it can be done!

Comment: That would be why I posted it as a **comment** and not an answer.

Comment: Valid point, thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151289/discussion-between-miguel-mateo-and-quentin).

Comment: Why on earth would anyone close-vote this?

Comment: I agree  with @Quentin. The solution of yms should be solve your problem at least for now, but if your are looking for a more robust solution that's not the way. I suggest that evaluate the use of xpath, is a good tool to do that.

Comment: And I explain the same, I had a solution working, using regex, now I have new data, which is very limited and well structured, changing the regex is the obvious solution, as long as you know regex.  Using XML parsers, compilers or anything else, while robust and elegant is unnecessary.

Comment: I upvoted the accepted answer, because it strictly adheres to what the asker asked for, in spite of all the warnings, but I can't avoid adding myself to the choir of people warning against using regex for this purpose. Things like `<p data-something=">" style="content('>')">hello</p>` Could ruin your day. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, since there is a lot of heat of the kind "this should not be done using regex", this is the solution.  Original XML:

```
<p class="myText" style="...">some text here</p>
```

Original regex to solve it:

```
<p\sclass=\"myText\"[^>]*>([^<]*)</p>
```

Please note the use of the ^ operator, that fails when the XML changes to:

```
<p class="myText" style="...">some <b style="...">bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text here</p>
```

Hence the solution regex is:

```
<p\sclass=\"myText\".+?>(.*?)<\/p>
```

Please note the elimination of the ^ operator and the introduction of the ? operator, that is the main difference.  The removal of the ^ looks for anything until an open angular bracket, the ? operator stop the regex from being greedy and stops the match on the first open angular bracket found.

Awesome no?  And people keep fighting to put XML parsers for something so simple and super fast!

Answer (score 3):

Use [lazy mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) to look for the first instance of '>' in your string:

```
<p.+?>(.*)<\/p>
```

Test it here:
https://regex101.com/r/Lz7GT0/1

If you want to process more than one match inside the same string, all you need to do is [use a stateful parser and call match multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7280586/501196).

Try it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jarn851m/

Comment: Thank you, nice attempt, the problem (my fault for not explaining it) is that the content of the API is a string of more than one 'p' tags, so something like this:

<p class="myText" style="test">some <b style="test">bold</b> and <i>italic</I> text here</p>with more text and other XML code that it is not important and then<p class="myText" style="test">other text</p>

Comment: Just use `(.*?)` instead of the greedy version `(.*)` to make sure the match ends when it finds the first `</p>` instead of going through the entire line (or text if the regex is multiline) until it finds the last `</p>`